# как грамотно реализовать mod_rewrite с 3-мя условиями?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, ssl, https, mod-rewrite

Есть вот такой rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Нужно в него еще добавить http => https

Как это реализовать? проверил погуглить, но изменения которые я находил приводили к тому что сайт без конца перезагружался

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

или

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

в зависимости от того, в какой переменной *https* отражается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Извините но у меня мало знаний по этой части что значит "в какой переменной https отражается". И если вам не трудно можете ли обьяснить вот это условие: "%{SERVER_PORT} !^443$" ?

Comment: 1-ый код выдал ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: `%{SERVER_PORT}` переменная, которая содержит значение номера порта на который пришел запрос. Обычно `80` - это порт отвечающий за `http` запросы, а 443 - за `https` запросы. Вы можете в php скрипте разместить команду `phpinfo();` и браузере увидеть конфигурацию php, в том числе переменные из массива SERVER в которых указана переменная SERVER_PORT/HTTPS.

Comment: спасибо, значит мне нужен первый вариант с изменениями, чтобы не выдавалась ошибка ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Можете помочь?

Comment: @HasanaghaAliyev, почему именно первый вариант, а не второй? Покажите таблицу массива _SERVER, которая выводится по phpinfo(); при открытии страницы по https протоколу.

Comment: Спасибо @Visman Но я нашел более удобный и гарантированный метод. Оказывается все это можно настроить через Cloudflare)))